# How to decrease size of SQL Server 2014 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server 2014 database dump which is approx. 60GB large. In SQL Server Management Studio, it is shown for the original DB, that the "ROWS Data" has an initial size of ~ 99000MB and the "LOG" has an initial size of ~ 25600MB.

Now there are a view tables in the Database which are about 10GB large and which I can flush/clean.

After deleting the data inside those tables, what is the best way to decrease the physical size of the database? A lot of posts I discovered are dealing with SHRINKDATABASE but some articles won't recommend it because of bad fragmentation and performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you'd want to shrink it? Because even if you shrink it, it will start growing in size again. Also, those recommendations not to do it are spot on. You may hurt SQL performance if you shrink your database.

Comment: Yes we need to get it as small as possible because we need to share it and the data inside the tables which we can delete is about 40GB in total. So there is a lot of potential.

Comment: The reason people won't recommend to SHRINK is because it's not the "right" strategy for handling databases running in production environments. If you need to deploy a version test or development or share it with other developers or something similar - I see little reason why you would fear the shrink. So depending on what you're actually trying to achieve - shrink might be viable. Just don't do it on the production version unless you're sure of what you're doing. (I've shrunk plenty of databases over the years - not my first choice, but well -it's a tool in the box)

Comment: Put those tables into separate FILEGROUP or even separate DB. And shrink only that DB/files if you need to. Also situation with LOG is not clear: is it in FULL recovery mode? Are you making DB and/or LOG backups?

Comment: The original database is in FULL recovery mode, so i guess the database dump i got is the same. Since the original database is in sum ~ 130GB and the dump only 60GB, is there a way to decrease the initial size? When i want to import a 60GB database into a 100GB filesystem, i got an error that the system needs 130GB free space in order to import the dump.

Comment: Here are the links about reduce the database size and improve performance in SQL Server http://aboutsqlserver.com/2014/12/02/size-does-matter-10-ways-to-reduce-the-database-size-and-improve-performance-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I have used to reduce the space used and free up Database space and actual Drive space. Hope this helps.

```
USE YourDataBase;
GO
-- Truncate the log by changing the database recovery model to SIMPLE.
ALTER DATABASE YourDataBase
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
-- Shrink the truncated log file to 1 MB.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (YourDataBase_log, 1);
GO
-- Reset the database recovery model.
ALTER DATABASE YourDataBase
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

Comment: ShrinkDatabase: shrink all files
ShrinkFile: just one file
For example, you may have a log backup issue and it's grown out of control so you run DBCC SHRINKFILE.

You almost never use ShrinkDatabase.

Comment: Some useful links for you to read.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189080(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: http://aboutsqlserver.com/2014/12/02/size-does-matter-10-ways-to-reduce-the-database-size-and-improve-performance-in-sql-server/

Comment: The only thing: if this scenario is okay for his DB, then there is no need to switch back to FULL. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use DBCC SHRINKDATABASE I suggest you to use
[DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms189493.aspx), obviously your tables should be stored on different FILEGROUP.
Then you can reduce the physical size of your database optimizing fragmentation.

Hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

You need to shrink your `DataBase` by using below Query.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
DBCC SHRINKFILE(PTechJew_LOG, 1)
ALTER DATABASE [DBNAME] SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT
```

After run this query check your log file.
Its Worked.